# Recursively insert an element into a list

Tags: prolog

I want to write a Prolog program to insert a list in another list. For example:

```
% insert [1, 2] to [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5]]
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 5], [1, 2]]
```

I wrote the following:

```
insertList([X], [], [[X]]).
insertList([H|T], [H2|T2], [[H|T], H2|T2]).
```

But this approach adds one list only, because there is no recursion. How can I make the recursion in this case? I had the same problem while inserting elements to a list in this code:

```
insert(X, [], [X]).
insert(X, [H|T], [X,H|T]).
```

So, how do I make a recursion to inserting the list? The insertion can be either in the beginning, or in the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently what you want is to insert an item at the end of a list.  The fact that the item being inserted is a list does not make a critical difference here.

```
insertAtEnd(X,[ ],[X]).
insertAtEnd(X,[H|T],[H|Z]) :- insertAtEnd(X,T,Z).
```

If you wanted instead to insert at the beginning, no recursion is needed!  In fact you don't even need a predicate to do this since the Prolog term `[X|L]` "inserts" the item X at the beginning of list L.

Perhaps you have in mind a more difficult problem, namely inserting an item into a sorted list in a proper way to maintain the sorted order.  However there's not much in the Question to suggest that this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to look at the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824802/recursion-in-prolog-on-lists) where the first answer contains a link to a site with explanation of recursion in prolog. It's a good starting point to get the hang of the mentioned problems.